# Xiaomi Redmi 4A astrophotography

Tags: astrophotography, smartphone

i own a Xiaomi Redmi 4A smartphone and i have access to fairly dark site to observe the night sky.I would like to know if it is possible to get a good photo of the milky way.

(f/2.2 , I can choose iso between 100-3200 and whatever shutter speed i want)

Comment: I tried to took some picture of the milky way with my S9 plus with f/1.7, iso 3200 and lowest shutter speed (i don't remember how much) and it was horrible!
So i don't think you can take some good photos. Too much artifact

Comment: @xiota Wow — even the same phone!

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it will be hard. You will need to

- set up your phone somewhere stable.
- Have it take multiple exposures, each for as long as you possibly can.
- Have it take them in RAW.
- Then import them into your computer.
- Open them in photoshop and align them.
- Stack them using median stack. Adjust colors and curves accordingly.

Using this I have been able to capture the milkyway using a Galaxy S7, but your results may vary.

This is what I captured, although it was heavily compress by Instagram, plus some poor editing:
[image]